# Using primary key from intermediary model as foreign key in django

Tags: django-models

I have two models with many to many relationship through an intermediary model. Is it possible to use primary key from the intermediary model as foreignkey in another model?

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    teachers = models.ManyToManyField(Teacher, through='Teacher_Course')
class Teacher_Course(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=CASCADE)
    allotedLectures = models.IntegerField()
class Lecture(models.Model):
    teacher_course = models.ForeignKey(Teacher_Course)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Is it valid to use ForeignKey relation in the Lecture model in this way?

Comment: Could you maybe show us your code? What have you tried? Help us help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have created the through table as a model explicitly it will have a PK, which means that other tables can use that as a FK. TL;DR, yes.